# apply different probabilites to different matrix columns for binomial result

Tags: matrix

I'm very new to modelling in R. I need to insert 0 and 1 into an empty matrix based on a probability. The probabilities differ for every 2 columns.
for example:

`#my empty matrix PopulationA = matrix(0,35,8) #probability of infection Infprob <- c(0.01, 0.50, 0.09, 0.4)`

I know how to apply a probability to the whole matrix using sapply (shown below). But I'm not able to apply different values to different columns for a binomial result.

`#applying probability to whole matrix prevalence <- 0.01 Pregnant <- sapply(15:50 ,function(p) rbinom(35000,1,prevalence))`

Thank you!